# Собирать данные о приложении

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте, посоветуйте материал по тому как из приложения собирать данные (сведения) о другом приложении. Я хочу написать приложение которое будет мониторить и выводить  время использования другого приложения. Напирер фб.